# Avoid background processing in Android application

Tags: android, phone-call

I am developing an application for a recognized financial institution. It is very important for them to manage security, and one of the requirements is that the application cannot run in the background. It was specifically requested that if a phone call is received, the application must get killed.

I tried using BroadcasterReceiver, by starting an activity when I hang up a call but apparently it runs as a service, and while my application is no longer running the activity is always started.
Is there any way to avoid background processing, like in iOS?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Sorry my english is not so good.

Comment: Maybe this can help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/android-is-application-running-in-background

Answer (score 0):

`onPause()` is called when your activity is going into the background.

If you overrode `onPause()` and stopped any sensitive activity in there, you would always catch the Activity going into the background.

Comment: I have a lot of activities and I need to keep a stack of Activities at any time, so if I start another activity it going to the background also